# python- flagging a second set of items in a series

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column which contains a list of numbers from a .csv. These numbers range from 1-1400 and may or may not be repeated and the a NaN value can appear pretty much anywhere at random.

Two examples would be

```
a=[1,4,NaN,5,6,7,...1398,1400,1,2,3,NaN,8,9,...,1398,NaN]

b=[1,NaN,2,3,4,NaN,7,10,...,1398,1399,1400]
```

I would like to create another column that finds the first 1-1400 and records a '1' in the same index and if the second set of 1-1400 exists, then mark that down as a '2' in the new column

I can think of some roundabout ways using temporary placeholders and some other kind of checks, but I was wondering if there was a 1-3 liner to do this operation

Edit1: I would prefer there to be a single column returned

```
a1=[1,1,NaN,1,1,1,...1,1,2,2,2,NaN,2,2,...,2,NaN]

b1=[1,NaN,1,1,1,NaN,1,1,...,1,1,1]
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Are you looking at adding 1 or 2 news columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `diff` to check when the difference between two following values is negative, meaning of the start of a new range. Let's create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# to create a dataframe with two columns my range go up to 12 but 1400 is the same
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,np.nan,5,10,12,2,3,4,np.nan,8,12],'b':range(1,13)})
df.loc[[4,8],'b'] = np.nan
```

Because you have 'NaN', you need to use `ffill` to fill `NaN` with previous value and you want the opposite of the row (using `~`) where the `diff` is greater or equal than 0 (I know it sound like less than 0, but not exactely here as it miss the first row of the dataframe). For column 'a' for example

```
print (df.loc[~(df.a.ffill().diff()>=0),'a'])
0    1.0
6    2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

you get the two rows where a "new" range start. To use this property to create 'a1', you can do:

```
# put 1 in the rows with a new range start
df.loc[~(df.a.ffill().diff()>=0),'a1'] = 1
# create a mask to select notnull row in a:
mask_a = df.a.notnull()
# use cumsum and ffill on column a1 with the mask_a
df.loc[mask_a,'a1'] = df.loc[mask_a,'a1'].cumsum().ffill()
```

Finally, for several column, you can do:

```
list_col = ['a','b']
for col in list_col:
    df.loc[~(df[col].ffill().diff()>=0),col+'1'] = 1
    mask = df[col].notnull()
    df.loc[mask,col+'1'] = df.loc[mask,col+'1'].cumsum().ffill()
```

and with my input, you get:

```
       a     b   a1   b1
0    1.0   1.0  1.0  1.0
1    4.0   2.0  1.0  1.0
2    NaN   3.0  NaN  1.0
3    5.0   4.0  1.0  1.0
4   10.0   NaN  1.0  NaN
5   12.0   6.0  1.0  1.0
6    1.0   7.0  2.0  1.0
7    3.0   8.0  2.0  1.0
8    4.0   NaN  2.0  NaN
9    NaN  10.0  NaN  1.0
10   8.0  11.0  2.0  1.0
11  12.0  12.0  2.0  1.0
```

EDIT: you can even do it in one line for each column, same result:

```
df['a1'] = df[df.a.notnull()].a.diff().fillna(-1).lt(0).cumsum()
df['b1'] = df[df.b.notnull()].b.diff().fillna(-1).lt(0).cumsum()
```

Comment: I am going to mark this answer as correct based on the question I asked due to the single line at the end. There was a little more info that I did not provide in which the numbers are not always in descending order. I used a larger threshhold for the "changes" and since my values were strings i had to convert to float `df['a1'] = df[df.a.notnull()].a.astype('float').diff().fillna(-1001).lt(-1000).cumsum()`

Comment: @famousness1 indeed with this info, the solution is not working. But glad you find a way to change my answer to the solution of your bigger problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby()` and `cumcount()` to count numbers in each column:

```
# create new columns for counting
df['a1'] = np.nan
df['b1'] = np.nan

# take groupby for each value in column `a` and `b` and count each value
df.a1 = df.groupby('a').cumcount() + 1
df.b1 = df.groupby('b').cumcount() + 1

# set np.nan as it is
df.loc[df.a.isnull(), 'a1'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.b.isnull(), 'b1'] = np.nan
```

EDIT (after receiving a comment of 'does not work'):

```
df['a2'] = df.ffill().a.diff()
df['a1'] = df.loc[df.a2 < 0].groupby('a').cumcount() + 1
df['a1'] = df['a1'].bfill().shift(-1)
df.loc[df.a1.isnull(), 'a1'] = df.a1.max() + 1
df.drop('a2', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.loc[df.a.isnull(), 'a1'] = np.nan
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work since the values may not be repeated in the second set of 1-1400. In the example I gave the values of "2" and "3" in series 'a' appear for the first time in the second set of 1-1400. I tried running this and it flagged those with a 1 when they should be flagged as a 2.

Comment: you can use `ffill()` instead of `fillna(method='ffill')`, it's the same thing :)

Comment: @gyoza I learnt it by someone leaving a comment on one of my answer, I thought I would do the same thing ^^

Comment: @Ben.T Great! I will do the same :)